# Can i manage single lines inside of a Sprite?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm working on a drawing app and now there's one problem.
There are few thousand lines, that have to be drawn, but i also need to clear them one by one somehow. Or maybe - clear a square region inside Sprite's graphics.
For now i think about using array and push each line into new Sprite, so i can add this new sprites to parent. But this solution looks awful, cause new sprite object will be created for each line.
Is there some way to manage lines without creation sprite for them?

Comment: I will warn you now that that many lines is going to negatively affect the performance of your application on a significant scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a data object that represents each line. Then create a BitmapData object where you draw all the lines (for example, you could use fillRect() to draw a really narrow rect for each line). Clear out the rectangle (use fillRect() or floodFill()) before you need to change the representation, then just draw the lines that still apply.

Create a Bitmap with that BitmapData, and add it to the stage.

Note you should be able to easily represent several thousand lines with good performance. If you find yourself creating and destroying data objects that represent each line, look at [object pooling](http://www.flashandmath.com/flashcs4/fireworks/index.html).

Comment: `fillRect()` is only good for orthogonally aligned lines, for common lines use `draw()`. Otherwise, this is a good approach.

Comment: Why `fillRect()` when you have `moveTo()` and `lineTo()` methods for a `Graphics` object?

Comment: @Vesper fillRect() was only given as an example. For diagonal lines, I'd create a line on its own BitmapData and use copyPixels(), which is faster than draw(). For both copyPixels() and draw(), you have to have a source object, but for fillRect(), you don't.

Comment: @Gio--because it does not perform as well.

Comment: This implementation is exactly what i had before.
I can't just clear bitmap data and draw all thousands of lines again.

Comment: If it will happen often (and it will, cause this happens in ENTER_FRAME event) - it will be slow as hell. For now i decide to stay with multiple sprites. It work pretty well, i tested it - there's no any lags...

Comment: "Can't" is a bigger word than its four letters imply. CopyPixels() is lightning fast. I'm not sure why you think it isn't. Post your implementation and we can maybe help you tweak it.